# Insert with Stored Procedures and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying for the first time to create a simple Stored Procedure. I have scouted the net and found several of tutorials, but keep getting some errors when I try to create an INSERT procedure?

I'm trying this:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE my_insert(IN fname VARCHAR(50),IN lname VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN

SET @fname=fname; 
SET @lname=lname;

PREPARE STMT FROM 
"INSERT INTO users(fname,lname) VALUES (?,?)";

EXECUTE STMT USING @fname,@lname; 

END
```

I get this error:
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_insert(IN fname VARCHAR(50),IN lname VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN SET @fname=fn' at line 1**

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: have you forgotten the closing `//` delimiter at the end of the procedure, or did you just miss it when you copied+pasted the code into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used " instead of ' . Thats the error in your query. Correct query is given below

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE my_insert(IN fname VARCHAR(50),IN lname VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN

SET @fname=fname; 
SET @lname=lname;

PREPARE STMT FROM 
'INSERT INTO users(fname,lname) VALUES (?,?)';

EXECUTE STMT USING @fname,@lname; 

END //
```

Or you can simply use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE my_insert(IN fname VARCHAR(50),IN lname VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN
INSERT INTO users(`fname`,`lname`) VALUES (fname,lname);


END //
```

Comment: Works like a charm, allthough I found my error. In my original script I use insert( instead of my_insert(. Thats whay I got this error, but thanks though ;-)